# Translating Metamask Address to Alias

Tags: metamask

When using Metamask, the user can see transaction data before approve a transaction, like origin and destination.
Users can define alias to their accounts, so the origin is in general easy.

So, in general we can say the user see something like that

Origin       -> Destination
MyAccount1   -> 0xABCD1234567889...

Supposing a DAPP that always send transaction to the same contract, that is deployed at 0xABCD1234567889...
Is there a way to give a hint of what the destination address means? For example, if we create an alias to 0xABCD1234567889... using ENS (Ethereum Naming Service), does it reflect on how metamask presents the address?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per ENS documents,

> Which wallets and DApps support ENS so far?
>
> MyEtherWallet supports both registering names via the auction process
>   and sending funds and interacting with contracts identified by their
>   names.
>
> Metamask supports sending funds to ENS names...

So you could set the *to* address as an ENS

source: http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=metamask